# Handlebars.Net Each loop c#

Tags: c#, .net, handlebars.net

I have a JArray that contains an array of objects. I am using handlebars.net to bind the data in the template.

In getReportDetails variable, I am getting an array of objects in the below format

```
[
{
"index": 1,
"Name": "Adam",
},
{
"index": 2,
"Name": "Sdam",
}
];

var template = Handlebars.Compile(source);
_logger.Info(getReportDetails);
var getdata = template(getReportDetails);

<tbody>
   {{#each getReportDetails}}
    <tr>
    <td>{{Name}}</td>
    </tr></tbody>
```

In getdata variable data is not binding.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your array is root of your data object, so you should use `#each this`:

```
<tbody>
    {{#each this}}
```

Working example:

```
    var list = new List<X>() { new X() { Id=1 }, new X() { Id = 2} };
    var template = Handlebars.Compile("{{#each this}} xxx {{Id}} {{/each}}");
```